# How to change Label char once i've pressed the char on keyboard?

Tags: javafx

working on a game that consists of 3 chars, everytime i press one of the chars on my keyboard, it is supposed to change to another random character. I am unable to reason out how to change the char when I press it on my keyboard.

For example -> I open up a game, there is a window that has 3 chars (X Y S)
Once i press X on my keyboard, id like to change the first char to a new random character, what I've currently written is:

```
Label key1 = new Label();
key1.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial");
key1.setText(Methods.rndChar());  ////// I have a method in another class that generates a random character for this
key1.setTranslateX(110);
key1.setTranslateY(100);

root.getChildren().addAll(key1, key2, key3);

root.setOnKeyPressed( (KeyEvent event) -> {
    if (event.getCode().toString().equals(key1.toString())) {
       key1.setText(Methods.rndChar());
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I shortly discovered that my error had to do with my if condition. I changed it to:

if (event.getCode().toString().equals(key1.getText()))

And i now have it working.